# How to post language agnostic formulas for programmers?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to post "simple" math formulas on various StackExchange sites so that programmers using any popular language can cut/paste/use my formulas.

I'm familiar with $\LaTeX$ (which apparently doesn't work here, but you get the idea), and know you can even "right click" to convert it to MathML or "TeX commands", but most programming languages won't easily read either of those.

Is there a "standard form" for formulas that programmers can convert to their own language?

As an example, I wroteup some code at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ROSETTA/ to convert `{sqrt(cos(y) + sin(x)), sqrt(cos(x) + sin(y))}` (a two argument function returning a list of two elements) into several languages and printing the output when `x=1.5, y=2.3`. Note how similar the results are:

#### JavaScript

```
function testing0002(x,y) {return [Math.pow((Math.cos(y))+(Math.sin(x)),(1.0)/(2.0)), Math.pow((Math.cos(x))+(Math.sin(y)),(1.0)/(2.0))];}
print(testing0002(1.5,2.3));
```

#### Lua

```
function testing0002(x,y) return ((math.cos(y))+(math.sin(x)))^((1.0)/(2.0)), ((math.cos(x))+(math.sin(y)))^((1.0)/(2.0)) end
print(testing0002(1.5,2.3))
```

#### PHP

```
function testing0002($x,$y) {return array(pow((cos($y))+(sin($x)),(1.0)/(2.0)), pow((cos($x))+(sin($y)),(1.0)/(2.0)));}
print_r(testing0002(1.5,2.3));
```

#### Python

```
import math;
def testing0002(x,y):
 return [((math.cos(y))+(math.sin(x)))**((1.0)/(2.0)), ((math.cos(x))+(math.sin(y)))**((1.0)/(2.0))]

print(testing0002(1.5,2.3))
```

#### Ruby

```
def testing0002(x,y) [((Math.cos(y))+(Math.sin(x)))**((1.0)/(2.0)), ((Math.cos(x))+(Math.sin(y)))**((1.0)/(2.0))] end
print testing0002(1.5,2.3),"\n"
```

#### R

```
testing0002 <- function(x,y) {return(list(((cos(y))+(sin(x)))^((1.0)/(2.0)), ((cos(x))+(sin(y)))^((1.0)/(2.0))))}
print(testing0002(1.5,2.3))
```

Surely something like this must already exist?

If there is a better place to post this question, please let me know.

Comment: If you are asking about Stack Exchange, Stack Exchange doesn't have anything to do that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks. I didn't mean Stack Exchange specifically, but many subsites involve math and formulas, so I thought this would be a good general place to ask.

Comment: I think you're describing pseudocode, but as far as I'm aware there's no one standard for that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you're right, and I'm hoping there are least some partially usable efforts. LaTeX makes formulas look cool, but appears to be totally unusable by programmers (my target "audience") unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Added some examples to give better idea of what I mean.